# SSRS Paramater Not Returning Single Results

Tags: sql, reporting-services, parameters, parent-child

I currently have a report set up that returns a result based on 4 parameters. These parameters are @StartDate, @EndDate, @EmployeeID, and @SampleType, which are all pretty explainable. It is also grouped by sample type, then date.

The report looks like this (More or less):

```
    Sample Type    Employee Name   Date   Time Spent on Sample
    A              Name1           4/6     7
                   Name1           4/6     8
                   Name2           4/6     15
    B              Name1           4/6     12
                   Name2           4/6     11 
                   Name2           4/6     13
```

(Name is a calculated field, it is grouped by employeeID)
The report will return the correct result if there are multiple rows to return, but if there is only one row to return, it shows nothing. It doesn't do this with just a specific employeeID or specific SampleType, only when there is only one record to present. So, using the dummy report above, if @StartDate was 4/6 and @EndDate was 4/6, @EmployeeID was Name1, and @SampleType was B, the preview will show not a single result. But if @EmployeeID was Name2, it would both rows.

Is there any obvious reason that I'm overlooking that is preventing the parameter to work correctly when only one row should return?

Below is a copy of the query:

```
    SELECT        MasterSampleDescription, CollectedDateTime, LabArrivalDateTime, CreatedDateTime, TimeDiffCollectLab, TimeDiffLabCreate, TimeDiffCollectCreate, 
                     TimeDiffCollectStart, TimeDiffCollectEnd, TimeDiffSampleStartEnd, SampleStart, SampleEnd, FirstName, LastName, AVG(TimeDiffCollectEnd) AS AvgTimeDiffCollect, 
                     TimeDiffLabArrivalSampleEnd, TimeDiffCreationStart, UserID
    FROM            vwTimeAnalysis
    WHERE        (CollectedDateTime >= @StartDate) AND (CollectedDateTime < DATEADD(Day, 1, @EndDate))
    GROUP BY MasterSampleDescription, CollectedDateTime, LabArrivalDateTime, CreatedDateTime, TimeDiffCollectLab, TimeDiffLabCreate, TimeDiffCollectCreate, 
                     TimeDiffCollectStart, TimeDiffCollectEnd, TimeDiffSampleStartEnd, SampleStart, SampleEnd, FirstName, LastName, TimeDiffLabArrivalSampleEnd, 
                     TimeDiffCreationStart, UserID
    HAVING        (UserID = @EmployeeName) AND (MasterSampleDescription = @SampleType)
    ORDER BY CollectedDateTime, LastName, MasterSampleDescription
```

Comment: The HAVING clause is intended for aggregate function conditions.

Comment: My bad, QueryDesigner defaults those filters to HAVING instead of WHERE. Corrected the query, still not seeing the desired results. It pulls the row correctly from the query, but fails to display them in the report.

Comment: This sounds more like an SSRS problem than a query problem.  Can you give us more info on the (presumably matrix) control set-up?  Anything special going on there?  What is your group def'n?

Comment: If by "the preview" you mean the Preview tab in Visual Studio, then I would ignore this. It is often unreliable / misleading. Deploy your report and test it as your users will run it.

Comment: @MikeHoney Thanks. It apparently works in Dev, just not inside the Preview tab in Visual Studio. Had me a frenzy for no reason. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If by "the preview" you mean the Preview tab in Visual Studio, then I would ignore this. It is often unreliable / misleading. Deploy your report and test it as your users will run it.